# Differentiable around a point

Tags: real-analysis

I was hoping someone could help me with the following. In my lecture notes I have the following theorem: "If $f$ is differentiable around $a$ and if $f$ has a local maximum or local minimum at $a$, then $f'(a)=0$

My question has to do with the word "around". I was wondering how I can formalise what "around" means in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, "$f$ is differentiable around $a$" means "there is some open interval containing $a$ on which $f$ is differentiable." That is, for some $r>0$, the derivative $f'(x)$ exists whenever $$a-r<x<a+r.$$

Answer (score 1):

In analysis, around is a reference to the topology of the space.

"Around $a$" means "in an open subset containing $a$", or in a metric space: "in an open ball with center $a$".

Answer (score 0):

By "around" one usually means a sufficiently small open neighborhood of the point $a$. So, if $a\in B$, then let $T$ be a topology of $B$.

Then, by "around" one usually means a sufficiently small open set $U$ such that $\exists V\in T$ such that $x\in V$, and $V\subseteq U$, of the point $a\in B$.